# Is it possible to use the Go compiler to distribute a executable file for other os?

Tags: windows, macos, go, compiler-construction

I am currently working on Mac OS X, now I need to build a .exe file so that the Go program can run on windows. 
So here is the question, how to build a executable file for Win X86 under MacOS amd64 ? or Is it impossible to do so ?

Comment: See also http://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/WindowsCrossCompiling

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168873/cross-compile-go-on-osx

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you don't use CGo but pure Go, then it's perfectly doable and standard.

First you have to make the Go environment on your development computer for the targets. Supposing your Go installation is in `~/var/go`, this may be this :

```
cd ~/var/go/src
CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=windows GOARCH=386 ./make.bash
```

Then you compile with the good GOOS and GOARCH :

```
GOOS=windows GOARCH=386 go build -o hello.exe hello.go
```

Here's [the go-wiki page on building a windows exe on linux](http://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/WindowsCrossCompiling).

Comment: So you are trying to say that its possible i am sitting in OSX 10.10.2. And via OSX i can compile and build a package for Linux or Windows?

Comment: @YumYumYum That's the idea, yes

Answer (score 8):

I've used [Dave Cheney's tutorial](http://dave.cheney.net/2012/09/08/an-introduction-to-cross-compilation-with-go) and accompanying shell scripts to build binaries for linux, windows and OS X on linux just fine. (Used by my [stressdisk](https://github.com/ncw/stressdisk) project)

It is exactly the same method as described by dystroy just with step by step instructions and a few helpful shell aliases.

**Update Feb 2021**

If you want to plug something into your CI then I recommend [goreleaser](https://goreleaser.com/) - this can automatically cross compile for a variety of OSes and build packages too. If you want to see an example check out [the stressdisk releases page](https://github.com/ncw/stressdisk/releases) built entirely with goreleaser - see [the config](https://github.com/ncw/stressdisk/blob/master/.goreleaser.yml) and [the instructions](https://github.com/ncw/stressdisk/blob/master/RELEASE.md)

Comment: Thinks, I'll try it later. ;-)

Comment: woah, the blog you linked is so dense & useful! Thanks :)