# go build runtime: darwin/amd64 must be bootstrapped using make.bash

Tags: macos, go, cross-compiling, darwin

I install `golang` with `brew install go` in my mac `osx 10.10.4`, when I run `go build` I got:

```
go build runtime: darwin/amd64 must be bootstrapped using make.bash
```

then refer to the question [Cross compile Go on OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168873/cross-compile-go-on-osx)

first I tried:

```
brew install go --with-cc-all
```

but question remain, then I tried:

```
cd /usr/local/go/src
sudo GOOS=darwin GOARCH=amd64 CGO_ENABLED=0 ./make.bash --no-clean
```

but the question still remains. So how can I fix this?

```
System Version: OS X 10.10.4 (14E46)
Kernel Version: Darwin 14.4.0
Go Version: go version go1.4.2 darwin/amd64
```

Comment: That's odd. Try `brew uninstall go && brew clean` and then `go install` again. Homebrew should handle the build process itself.

Comment: @elithrar the problems remain. But one thing needs pay attention: I copy the `GOROOT` and `GOPATH` directory to Mac, so is this a problem?

Comment: Of course it is! You must be copying them from a different architecture. Definitely don't do that.

Comment: @elithrar so I should recompile them all?

Comment: Just install them using `brew install go` (after deleting what you copied). Don't "copy" anything over from elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I built it from [source](https://golang.org/doc/install/source#environment). This is what I've done:

From the checkout source, in `src`:

```
src $ GOOS=darwin GOARCH=amd64 ./bootstrap.bash
#### Copying to ../../go-darwin-amd64-bootstrap
...
----
Bootstrap toolchain for darwin/amd64 installed in XXX/go-darwin-amd64-bootstrap.
Building tbz.
-rw-r--r--  1 hvn  staff  48149988 Aug 21 10:48 XXX/go-darwin-amd64-bootstrap.tbz
```

Then I unarchive the tbz and build it as normal:

```
$ tar xzf XXX/go-darwin-amd64-bootstrap.tbz
```

cd to that extracted dir. Then

```
$ ./all.bash
##### Building Go bootstrap tool.
cmd/dist
...

ALL TESTS PASSED

---
Installed Go for darwin/amd64...

$ go-darwin-amd64-bootstrap/bin/go version
go version go1.5 darwin/amd64
```

Hope that help.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem.

What I did was reinstall Go since I have an existing brew installation

`brew reinstall go --with-cc-all`

When I tried `goax` command, the problem was fixed