# Run go program without Go environment

Tags: go, docker

I wrote a program in Go and I want to launch it in a Docker container, but my company does not have a golang Docker image and refuses to download one.

I only have an image with Java (CentOS). How can I achieve this? Is it possible to run some kind of binary thing which does not need Go environment?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Who downvoted my question, that's not kind

Answer (score 3):

You don't need docker or a go SDK environment to run go executables. 
Simply cross compile [stackoverflow Q: 12168873](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168873/cross-compile-go-on-osx) the go program on the pc you wrote it and copy the binary to the computer with CentOS, given that computer has a supported hardware.